# Using jquery and ajax to update a partial using Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I've had this issue for days and been unable to figure it out...  I have 'Like' and 'Unlike' button. When a user "likes" a post, the updates should occur in the data base and then the button should flip to "unlike". Everything works on the backend - the database updates just fine, however the button never switches from "Like" to "Unlike".  If I manually refresh the page it will be switched, but it doesn't happen without the refresh. I do not have any errors logged or in the console.

shared/_like.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(current_user.likes.build, remote: true) do |f| %>
<div><%= hidden_field_tag :post_id, post.id %></div>
<%= f.submit "Like", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

shared/_unlike.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(current_user.likes.find_by_post_id(post.id),
html: {method: :delete },
remote: true) do |f| %>
<%= f. submit "Unlike", class: "btn" %>
<% end %>
```

These are rendered through:
post/_post.html.erb

```
<div id="like_form">
    <% if post.does_user_like(post.id, current_user.id) %>
        <%= render 'shared/unlike', :post => post %>
    <% else %>                  
        <%= render 'shared/like', :post => post %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

likes/create.js.erb

```
$("#like_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('shared/unlike', :post => @post)) %>");
```

Likes Controller

```
def create
      user = current_user    
      post = post.find(params[:post_id])
      @post = post
      Like.create(post_id: post.id, user_id: user.id)     
      respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to request.referrer || root_url }
            format.js 
          end
  end
```

Comment: This won't work as the rails server will render a page containing only one of your partials (like or unlike). The ruby code which decides which partial to render runs on your server, so it won't do anything until you reload the page. You should load both partials, and hide one of the forms. You should then manage your AJAX call from JavaScript (using something like `.on("click", ...)`, and change the button if the server replies with a success.

Comment: @taglia I followed the same logic as Michael Hartl in his Rails tutorial.  See here: https://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users#code-follow_form and here: https://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users#code-create_js_erb.  This works great for the follow/unfollow button.

Comment: There's a big difference: Michael does not send the request via AJAX, thus the page will be reloaded and everything will work fine.

Comment: @taglia, i believe he does use ajax. Words directly from the tutorial: "Having updated the form, we now need to arrange for the Relationships controller to respond to Ajax requests."  My code syntax is identical to his. Here is his call: <%= form_for(current_user.active_relationships.build, remote: true) do |f| %> and his response: respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to user }
  format.js
end

Comment: @taglia: due to `remote: true`, the partial is used for updating the page, not for rendering from scratch.

Comment: @tillmo  you are right, I read the question quickly before going to a meeting and misunderstood. Apologies user2884789.

Answer (score 0):

use `replaceWith` instead of `html` in `likes/create.js.erb`

Comment: I discovered that when I added location.reload(); to create.js.erb the page will refresh and it works as it should, however I know there is a way to do this without forcing a refresh as Hartl did it in his tutorial.  So this question is still not quite answered...

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the issue: the code here:

```
<div id="like_form">
    <% if post.does_user_like(post.id, current_user.id) %>
        <%= render 'shared/unlike', :post => post %>
    <% else %>                  
        <%= render 'shared/like', :post => post %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Is actually a feed of posts - so there are many posts per page.  The issue was that the code was all actually working fine, but it was updating the first post on the page, rather than the correct post.  I solved the issue by putting and id on each div:

```
<div id="like_form-<%=post.id %>">
    <% if post.does_user_like(post.id, current_user.id) %>
        <%= render 'shared/unlike', :post => post %>
    <% else %>                  
        <%= render 'shared/like', :post => post %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

And calling the specific div here:

```
$("#like_form-<%=@post.id %>").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('shared/unlike', :post => @post)) %>")
```